# Sum per group with a condition in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to sum each group with a condition. I have the following data

```
a<-data.table (facto=c ("a","b","a","a","b","b","b"), value = c (2,3,2,3,2,2,2))

    facto value
1:     a     2
2:     b     3
3:     a     2
4:     a     3
5:     b     2
6:     b     2
7:     b     2
```

and I'd like to compute the sum of facto which their value is not equal to 3 using `data.table`.

I used this code

```
output <-a[, (value=sum(value!=3)), .(facto)]
```

and it gives me the following data that counts the row which are not equal to 3 for each group:

```
   facto V1
1:     a  2
2:     b  3
```

However, I wish to have the following output:

```
       facto V1
    1:     a  4
    2:     b  6
```

Comment: `DT[i, j, by]`. i j by is analogous to SQL: WHERE SELECT GROUP BY. In words: "Take `data.table`, subset rows using `i`, then calculate `j` grouped by `by`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the logical condition in `i` and get the `sum` of 'value' by `facto`

```
a[value!=3, sum(value), by = facto]
#   facto V1
#1:     a  4
#2:     b  6
```

Also, the OP's code is getting the `sum` of logical index and not the `value` after subsetting

```
a[, (value=sum(value[value!=3])), .(facto)]
```

Comment: This will omit any groups that are all threes, but I guess should just have zero in such cases.

Comment: @Frank You are right.  Not sure about what the OP wanted in those case.